# Using regex replace in SSMS 2016 to trim lines

Tags: regex, ssms, regex-greedy, ssms-2016

How can I use SSMS 2016 regex replace feature to remove extra spaces and tabs at the end of lines?

**Example of editor content:**

```
select
    'tab'   
,   'space' 

select
    'tabs'      
,   'spaces'
```

**Goal:**

```
select
    'tab'
,   'space'

select
    'tabs'
,   'spaces'
```

In SSMS 2012 find string `:b*$` matches those extra tabs and spaces and allows me to replace them with nothing. SSMS 2016 started using some kind of .net regex syntax for the find/replace feature. Using `\s+$` almost works in 2016, but it removes the empty lines.

Comment: Try using `[\p{Zs}\t]+$`

Comment: `[\p{Zs}\t]+$` matches the two spaces on last line, nothing else.

Comment: That means you need to turn on multiline mode with `(?m)`. `(?m)[\p{Zs}\t]+$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove trailing *horizontal* whitespace from the end of the *lines* with a .NET regex, you need to use

```
(?m)[\p{Zs}\t]+$
```

The multiline modifier `(?m)` is necessary to make the `$` anchor match end of *lines* rather than the whole strings. The `\p{Zs}` matches any Unicode *horizontal* whitespace but a tab char, thus, we need to add `\t` and `\p{Zs}` into a character class `[...]`. The `+` quantifier will match 1 or more occurrences of these whitespaces.

An alternative that does not rely on a multiline modifier:

```
[^\S\r\n]+(\r?\n|$)
```

and replace with `$1` backreference (that re-inserts the text *captured* by the first (and only) *capturing group* in the pattern, i.e. to preserve end-of-lines in the output).

**Details**:

- `[^\S\r\n]+` - matches 1 or more characters other than non-whitespaces, CRs and LFs (basically, an `\s` with the exception of `\r` and `\n`)
- `(\r?\n|$)` - matches either at the end of the line (*optional* CR, *carriage return*, and *obligatory* LF, *newline*) or at the end of the *string* (`$`).

Comment: `(?m)[\p{Zs}\t]+$` also only matches the spaces on last lines. SSMS 2016 regex syntax may be somehow limited.

Comment: Try a replacement with a capturing group that should work even in JavaScript. `[^\S\r\n]+(\r?\n?)` -> `$1`

Comment: The alternative removes all spaces and tabs. Leading whitespaces should be left as they are.

Comment: Sorry, sure, I made a mistake. Fixed. I thought about a different case. `(\r?\n|$)` will match either at the end of the line (optional CR and *obligatory* LF) *or* at the end of the line.

Comment: Find: `[^\S\r\n]+(\r?\n|$)`, replace by `$1` works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: None of the provided answers have worked for me. It just says that it couldnt find it. I can clearly see newlines in the file.

Comment: @Preza8 It does not mean the answer is wrong and is worth downvoting. If you need help, post a separate question, or at least let others help you - but tell exaclty what your input is. Downvoting is OK when the answer is poorly formatted, does not answer the question, code only, spam, but it is not the case.

Comment: @Preza8 BTW, the question is not about newlines, but about horizontal whitespace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right in both comments, I apologize. Thanks for telling me. Unfortunately my vote is locked.